# Scrapy Splash cannot get the data of a React site

Tags: python, reactjs, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I need to scrape [this](https://www.jumbo.cl/lacteos-y-bebidas-vegetales/leches-blancas?page=6) site.
Is made in React so it looks. Then I tried to extract the data with scrapy-splash. I need for example the "a" element with class `shelf-product-name`. But the response is an empty array. I used the `wait` argument in about 5 seconds.
But I only get an empty array.

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url='https://www.jumbo.cl/lacteos-y-bebidas-vegetales/leches-blancas?page=6',
            callback=self.parse,
            args={'wait':5}
        )

def parse(self,response):
        print(response.css("a.shelf-product-name"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no need to use Scrapy Splash because all required data stored inside `<script>` tag of raw html response as json formatted data:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import json

class JumboCLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "JumboCl"
    start_urls = ["https://www.jumbo.cl/lacteos-y-bebidas-vegetales/leches-blancas?page=6"]

    def parse(self,response):
        script = [script for script in response.css("script::text") if "window.__renderData" in script.extract()]
        if script:
            script = script[0]
        data = script.extract().split("window.__renderData = ")[-1]
        json_data = json.loads(data[:-1])
        for plp in json_data["plp"]["plp_products"]:
            for product in plp["data"]:
                #yield {"productName":product["productName"]} # data from css:  a.shelf-product-name
                yield product

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c.crawl(JumboCLSpider)
    c.start()
```